# CSS Opacity impacting text when not in div

Tags: html, css

Hi so am testing CSS background and div opacity but for some reason it also impacts the text when the text is not in the div...

The h2 text should be white since i added it in the css color: white but its not

What am i doing wrong please explain if you answer with a fix

Thank you.

```css
.bimg{
  background-size: cover;
  background: transparent no-repeat fixed;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2a2d36;
  opacity: .54;
  z-index: 9;
}

#container{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#intro{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#intro h2{
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 87px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="bimg" style="height: 831px; background-image: url(http://widewallpaper.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Anime-Wallpaper-1920x1080-064.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="intro">
      <h2>Testing this.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `overlay` does that - because it's on top of your div with h1. You can add this to `h1{position: absolute; z-index: 10;}`

Comment: Reduce your z-index of .overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `overlay` it's above the `content`. Change the content to relative positioning and change the z-index to some upper:

```css
.bimg{
  background-size: cover;
  background: transparent no-repeat fixed;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2a2d36;
  opacity: .54;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#intro{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#intro h2{
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 87px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="bimg" style="height: 831px; background-image: url(http://widewallpaper.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Anime-Wallpaper-1920x1080-064.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="intro">
      <h2>Testing this.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your overlay is positioned as absolute and has z-index value 9, which is above your container class put position:relative to container and z-index: 10.